# how to save ScratchCard in Shared preference?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a game in that the user needs to scratch a card and find out what kind of image is hiding,
for that, the image should be scratched only once and the scratch-card is stored in memory, how can I do that?

I found lots of codes to create a scratch card but none of them can save the scratch card.

Here's what I found:

https://github.com/D-clock/ScratchView

https://github.com/myinnos/AndroidScratchCard

https://github.com/skymansandy/scratchCardLayout

[How to create a Scratch Card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892632/how-to-create-a-scratch-card-in-android)

[How to create scratch card which allows user to scratch only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389468/how-to-create-scratch-card-which-allows-user-to-scratch-only-once)

Thanks as advance :)

Comment: if that image is coming from backend better save the image URL in shared preference.

Comment: @PavanNagaraja how i can do it?
i try a lot of options to save the Scratch but in the class didnt have a "get" method

Comment: you will fill the image beforehand right, so you will have the image URL, after scratch completed save that image URL in shared preference.

Comment: @PavanNagaraja im sorry but i dont understand, can you help me more?

Comment: first, get started with any of the libraries that can give you a callback like  onScratchCompleated() and start coding something and if you are stuck somewhere you can post your question with the code so ppl here in the community can help you.

Comment: @PavanNagaraja ok tnx

Answer (score 0):

Based on status of the scratch fetched from memory, you can either make the view scratchable or revealed.

Have a look at this library.
https://github.com/skymansandy/scratchCardLayout

the latest update has an extra api revealScratch(). That and resetScratch() exactly serves your use case.